# Lens IDE errror: Unable to read client-cert

Tags: kubernetes, client-certificates

I'm running minikube in my  WSL(Ubuntu distro). But whenever I tried to connect minikube through lens it shows me the error that "system cannot find the path specified." / Unable to read client-cert. What should I do, any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: your minikube is up and running and accessible over cli ? https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8363 ?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used minikube but I have used Lens. Looking at your error message the path to the certificates looks rather convoluted, so I'm wondering whether the config is wrong.

I would suggest opening a shell in WSL and seeing if you can find the files at those locations.

With a fresh shell, and you typing pwd I'd expect to see:

```
% pwd
/home/linux
```

If so, I'd try cd'ing into the next directory as shown in the error message and checking that the path exists, continuing from above for example:

```
% pwd
/home/linux
% cd .kube
% cd home
% cd linux
% cd .minikube
% cd profiles
% cd minikube
% ls -l
```

What I suspect will happen is one of the cd commands will return with:

```
cd <directory-name>: No such file or directory
```

which shows that the config path is incorrect.

If you know where your kubeconfig file lives then it might just be simpler to add a new cluster in Lens, browse directly to the kubeconfig file and start fresh.

Good luck,
Tim

(I'm sorry if the cd suggestion above feels too simplistic but I don't know your level of experience so wouldn't want to offer an unhelpful answer.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. But it doesn't help, all thecd commands are executed. Is there any other way to solve this issue? I also tried to solve this issue by adding kubeconfig file in lens cluster but also after that it shows the same error.

Comment: your issue has been fixed or not?

Comment: @SaiChandiniRouthu hello there, no my issue regarding lens not syncing with minikube is not fixed. can you please help me in that